# How can I inject dependency for Automapper Resolver in .Net Core 2.0 project

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

In my ASPNET Core 2.0 project, when adding a Cache Dependency to my CustomResolver, such dependency is not resolved. I have a complex dependency structure and many mapping profiles which I register as below:

```
services.AddAutomapper(typeof(Startup))
```

How can I successfully inject that dependency into my custom resolver?

I tried below link for reference:
https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/07/20/integrating-automapper-with-asp-net-core-di/
But I didn't get the ServiceLocator.Resolve(t) part [I'm new to .Net Core and DI stuff]

My resolver CustomResolver has below code:

```
public class ProductIdResolver : IValueResolver<Request.Product, Entities.Product, int>
{
private readonly ICacheService cacheService;

    public ProductIdResolver(ICacheService cacheService)
    {
        this.cacheService = cacheService;
    }

    public Entities.Product Resolve(Request.Product source, Entities.Product destination, int destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return null;

        var product = Mapper.Map<Entities.Product>(source);

        product.Id = TranformProductId(source);

        return product;
    }

    private int TranformProductId(Request.PBI source)
    {
        var frombase = cacheService.GetProducts().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Sku == source.Sku);

        if (frombase == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("Invalid Product");

        return frombase.Id;
    }
}
```

The resolver reference is inside my SharedProfile, which is called by both Create and Change profile (I broke those profile classes into a third one for code re-using).
The problem is that my CacheService is not being resolved by DI and I always get an "Error mapping types" exception.
For reference, my code works if I remove the CacheService object.

How can I successfully inject that dependency into my custom resolver?

Comment: I don't have an answer but I want to just note that the service locator is typically not the best way to handle DI

Answer (score 0):

you need to resolve the mapper with dependency injection. in your class constructor try to inject `IMapper` and instead of `Mapper` use your injected `IMapper`

your mistake is using `Mapper` directly, this way you are calling mapper statically and it hasn't any idea about your dependency resolver. 
but if you map using Imapper that itself is coming with DI, then it can resolve the other dependency for you.

the sample code is like this;

```
Class Sample{

    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    Sample(IMapper mapper){
        _mapper= mapper;
    }

    public IActionResult Method1(){
        var items= GetItems();
        var itemMapped= _mapper.Map<MapToThis>(items);
        return Ok(itemMapped);
    }
}
```